# C Using a file argument with GetOpt

Tags: c, file, getopt

Is there a better way to find the name of a file than just looping through argv[] looking for an argument that isn't a flag - ?

In this case, the flags can be entered in any order (so optind isn't going to help).

ie:

/program -p file.txt -s

/program -p -s file.txt -b

/program file.txt -p -s -a

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){


char option;
const char *optstring;
optstring = "rs:pih";


while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, optstring)) != EOF) {

    switch (option) {
        case 'r':
            //do something
            break;
        case 's':
          //etc etc 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page of `getopt()`,

> By default, getopt() permutes the contents of argv as it scans, so that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end.

So the order in which the options and non-option arguments are given doesn't matter.

Use `getopt()` to take care of the options and their arguments (if any). After that, check the value of `optind`.

As the man page says,

> The variable `optind` is the index of the next element to be processed in `argv`.

In your command, it seems that there is only one non-option argument. If that's the case after all the options have been correctly processed, `optind` must be equal to `argc-1`.

Also, in the `optstring` you have given, there is colon following `s`. That means if the option `-s` is there, it must have an argument.

```
while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, optstring)) != EOF) {
    switch (option) {
    case 'r':
        //do something
        break;
    case 's':
      //etc etc 
   }
}

//Now get the non-option argument
if(optind != argc-1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of arguments.");
    return 1;
}
fprintf(stdout, "\nNon-option argument: %s", argv[optind]);
```

Note: The options may be provided in any order but the argument of one option may not be given as the argument of another.